# Remove a particular token from a string

Tags: java, string

I have to remove a particular token from a String variable.

for eg:
If the String variable is like `"GUID+456709876790"` I need to remove the `"GUID+"` part from the string and only need `"456709876790"`.

How can it be done?

Comment: `"GUID+456709876790".substring(5); //should do the trick`

Comment: And, if you aren't sure it's at the start of the string, `string.replace("GUID+", "")` will definitely do it.

Comment: Also, if the token is not always in the string, Marko's solution is better

Comment: How can I remove anything that comes before "+" and "+" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String s = "GUID+456709876790";
String token = "GUID+";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf(token) + token.length());
// or s = s.replace(token, "");
```

Answer (score 7):

Two options:

- As you're just removing from the *start*, you can really easily use substring:

  ```
  text = text.substring(5);
  // Or possibly more clearly...
  text = text.substring("GUID+".length());
  ```
- To remove it *everywhere* in the string, just use replace:

  ```
  text = text.replace("GUID+", "");
  ```

Note the use of `String.replace()` in the latter case, rather than `String.replaceAll()` - the latter uses regular expressions, which would affect the meaning of `+`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using  `apache.commons.lang` library you can use `StringUtils` just do:

```
StringUtils.remove(yourString, token);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  String str = "GUID+456709876790"

 str.substring(str.indexOf("+")+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this one :

```
String a = "GUID+456709876790";
String s = a.replaceAll("\\D","");
```

I am assuming that you want only digits as I have used regex here  to remove any thing that is not a digit

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
String Line="test line 1234 abdc",aux;
token=new StringTokenizer(Line);

 while(token.hasMoreTokens())
   if(!("1234").equals(aux=token.nextToken())){ 
     new_line+= aux+" ";
     System.out.println("la nueva string es: "+ new_line);
   }
```