# How to remove everything that comes before a particular token, including the token from a String

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove a particular token from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356979/remove-a-particular-token-from-a-string)

This question is a continuation to my earlier question

> [Remove a particular token from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14356979/remove-a-particular-token-from-a-string)

I need to remove whatever that comes before the "+" and the "+" from the String.

How can it be done?

Comment: Several answers to your previous question do exactly that - what have you tried that did not work?

Comment: Accept right/appropriate correct answer for your previous question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [String#substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) and [String#indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) in combination

```
    String s=  "GUID+456709876790";
    System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf("+")+1));
```

Output:  456709876790

Answer (score 1):

If the String is in the format +text+, a regular expression may do the trick:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\+(.*)\\+.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("sdasdad+982347347+234234234");
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Here you go: " + m.group(1));
}
```

The entire recognised string is group 0, the content in the first bracket is group 1.